# Why udev USB port fixing rules are not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, udev

I'm using *Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server*. There is a modem pool attached to *one* USB port of the server. When modem is turned off and back on again, the `ttyUSB` numbers are changing. I need to fix that ports. So, I put rules below to the file under `/etc/udev/rules.d` and restart the *udev* service with `systemctl restart udev.service`

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/86-persistent-gsm-modem.rules 

KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.5:1.0", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", ATTRS{product}=="Quad RS232-HS", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI", NAME="ttyUSB0"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.5:1.1", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", ATTRS{product}=="Quad RS232-HS", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI", NAME="ttyUSB1"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.5:1.2", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", ATTRS{product}=="Quad RS232-HS", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI", NAME="ttyUSB2"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.5:1.3", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", ATTRS{product}=="Quad RS232-HS", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI", NAME="ttyUSB3"
```

When I turn off and back on again the modem still `ttyUSB` numbers are changing.

Is there a problem with rules, and how can I check if the rules are read by *udev* and executed?

Addition of udevadm output for /dev/ttyUSB0 for example.

```
udevadm info -a /dev/ttyUSB0

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{latency_timer}=="1"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.5:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Quad RS232-HS"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5':
    KERNELS=="1-1.5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0800"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.5"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="Quad RS232-HS"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="4960883"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="31"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.0-34-generic ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1a.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="24"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1a.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x3b3c"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="16"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="000f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8383"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, udev will no longer rename the kernel-assigned device names. (Among other reasons, how should it cope with being asked to rename to something that's already taken by another device?)

Instead, use `SYMLINK+="..."` to create symlinks under /dev with your names of choice, for example `SYMLINK+="ttyUSB-port0"`. (In fact the standard 60-serial.rules should already be creating symlinks under `/dev/serial/by-path` for you.)

Second, rules are processed *not* when udev starts, but only when the kernel sends out *uevents* indicating a new or changed device. To cause those manually, you need `udevadm trigger -s tty` (or just reconnect the device).

Comment: I restarted the service because, I want to service is definitely aware of the my new rule file is there. Not for triggering the `udev` to run that rules. I also written in the question that after restarted the service, I turned off and on device for make *kernel* to drop ports and triggering `udev`. Anyway I got the point about naming and symlinking. I'm going to try that way, even and even I'm going to check if there are symlinks created under `/dev/serial` by *60-serial.rules* first. Thanks.